# Why doesn't Javascript validate my html code?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is my first attempt at working with javascript and forms; for some reason my html website elements aren't being validated and I am not sure why. My goal with this form is trying to validate the elements that have an '*' next to them. For some reason the only element that is being validated is email and nothing else. Name, dates, the checkbox aren't. I have been trying to find a fix, but nothing seems to work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

    <h1>Travel Reservation Form</h1>
    <h4>* denotes mandotory field</h4>
    <form name="myForm" action="action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">


        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal Details</legend>
            <label class="align">Full name:<span>*</span></label> <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="James Bond">
            <br><br>

            <label class="align">Email<span>*</span></label>
            <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="james@gmail.com">
            <br><br>

            <label class="align">Date of Birth<span>*</span></label> <input type="date" name="DOB" placeholder="dd/mm/yy">

        </fieldset>
        <br>

        <label>Select Tour Package<span>*</span>:</label>
        <select name="package">
            <option value="1">Tokyo</option>
            <option value="2">Shanghai</option>
            <option value="3">Bangkok</option>
            <option value="4">Jakarta</option>
            <option value="5">Mumbai</option>
        </select>




        <label>Number of persons<span>*</span>:</label>
        <select name="party">
            <option value="1">One Adult</option>
            <option value="2">Two Adults</option>
            <option value="3">Three Adults</option>
            <option value="4">Four Adults</option>
            <option value="5">Five Adults</option>
        </select>

        <br><br>



        <label>Arrival Date<span>*</span>:</label> <input type="date" name="arrival" placeholder="dd/mm/yy">
        <br><br>


        <p>What Intrests you the most?<span>*</span>:</p>

        <input class="alignp" type="checkbox" name="interest" value="shopping"> Shopping <br><br>

        <input class="alignp"  type="checkbox" name="interest" value="dining"> Dining <br><br>

        <input class="alignp"  type="checkbox" name="interest" value="dancing"> Dancing <br><br>

        <input class="alignp"  type="checkbox" name="interest" value="SightS"> Sightseeing <br><br><br>



        <label>Discount Coupon code:</label> <input type="text" name="dis_code" value=""><br><br>



        <label>Terms and Conditions<span>*</span><input type="radio" name="tos" value="yes" checked>I agree</label>
        <input type="radio" name="tos" value="yes">I disagree





        <p>Please provide any additional information below:- </p>
        <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45" placeholder="Please type here...."></textarea><br><br>



        <button class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        <button class="btn-reset" type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>

    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript that is being linked in the html. I am unsure whether the issue is with my html code or with my javascript.

```
// JavaScript Document
function validateForm()
{
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var dob = document.forms["myForm"]["DOB"].value;
    var packages = document.forms["myForm"]["package"].value;
    var arrival = document.forms["myForm"]["arrival"].value;
    //var interest = document.forms["form"]["interest"].value;
    var ToS = document.forms["myForm"]["tos"].value;
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name="interest"]:checked');
    var matches = name.match(/\d+/g);


    if (matches != null) {
        alert("Name has a number in it!");
    }

    if (name == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    if (email == "") {
        alert("Email must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    if (dob == "") {
        alert("Date of Birth must not be empty");
        return false;
    }

    if (arrival == "") {
        alert("Arrival Date must not be empty");
        return false;
    }
    if(ToS == false) {
        alert("You must agree to the Terms of Service");
        return false;

    }

    if(validateEmail(email) == false){
        alert("Must enter a valid email");
    }


    re = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;

    if(dob != '' && !dob.match(re)) {
        alert("Invalid date format");
        return false;
    }

    if(arrival != '' && !arrival.match(re)) {
        alert("Invalid arrival date format") ;
        return false;
    }

    if(name.length >= 30){
        alert("Name must be less than 30 characters!");
        return false;

    }

    if(!checkbox){
        alert("Please select an interest!");
        return false;
    }

}

function validateEmail(email)
{
    return /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email);
}
```

Comment: Please post the JS code you are using to validate.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum required to display the issue. Maybe start with one control, get it validating correctly, then add more controls one at a time. If you get stuck on a particular control, post just the validation for that control. There are many, many questions on form validation here, so once you identify the issue likely there is an answer for it already.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @j08691 no errors in the console

Comment: @RobG I think I may have found the solution... very very amateur mistake. The names for the inputs are not the same as in the javascript, so mail is email in my javascript.

Comment: Have you considered using the [native form validation api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have no idea what your PHP form did, so I actually just pulled all the form code for now. There were a lot of little issues but honest mistakes. Example: you don't want a return statement after every validation if you want to continue validating the rest of the fields. I combined some separate validations into if/else's since they were validations on the same field. I used ID's to make my life easier and since I dumped the form code. Feel free to swap back to what you want. I also updated your regex since the date field returns YYYY/MM/DD. Since this doesn't post anywhere you can play with it for a while, before tying back into your php form. I also pulled the check for 30 characters and added a max field length to name. You could also set min and max date ranges for the date fields and a bunch of other things to help make the fields themselves more foolproof. There are also libraries that handle this kind of thing for you, you don't have to re-invent the wheel, but if you're just looking to play around with it this should get you started. Good Luck

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>Travel Reservation Form</h1>
    <h4>* denotes mandotory field</h4>


    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal Details</legend>
      <label class="align">Full name:<span>*</span></label> <input type="text" name="fullname" id='name' maxlength="30" placeholder="James Bond">
      <br><br>

      <label class="align">Email<span>*</span></label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="mail" placeholder="james@gmail.com">
      <br><br>

      <label class="align">Date of Birth<span>*</span></label> <input type="date" id="dob" name="DOB" placeholder="dd/mm/yy">

    </fieldset>
    <br>

    <label>Select Tour Package<span>*</span>:</label>
    <select id='package' name="package">
      <option value="1">Tokyo</option>
      <option value="2">Shanghai</option>
      <option value="3">Bangkok</option>
      <option value="4">Jakarta</option>
      <option value="5">Mumbai</option>
    </select>




    <label>Number of persons<span>*</span>:</label>
    <select name="party">
      <option value="1">One Adult</option>
      <option value="2">Two Adults</option>
      <option value="3">Three Adults</option>
      <option value="4">Four Adults</option>
      <option value="5">Five Adults</option>
    </select>

    <br><br>



    <label>Arrival Date<span>*</span>:</label> <input type="date" name="arrival" id="arrival" placeholder="dd/mm/yy">
    <br><br>


    <p>What Intrests you the most?<span>*</span>:</p>

    <input class="alignp" type="checkbox" name="interest" value="shopping"> Shopping <br><br>

    <input class="alignp" type="checkbox" name="interest" value="dining"> Dining <br><br>

    <input class="alignp" type="checkbox" name="interest" value="dancing"> Dancing <br><br>

    <input class="alignp" type="checkbox" name="interest" value="SightS"> Sightseeing <br><br><br>



    <label>Discount Coupon code:</label> <input type="text" name="dis_code" value=""><br><br>



    <label>Terms and Conditions<span>*</span>
      <input type="radio" name="tos" id="accpeted" value="agree" checked>I agree</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tos" id="unaccepted" value="disagree">I disagree





    <p>Please provide any additional information below:- </p>
    <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45" placeholder="Please type here...."></textarea><br><br>



    <button class="btn-submit" id="submit" onclick="return validateForm()">Submit</button>



  </div>

  <script>
    // JavaScript Document
    function validateForm() {
      var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
      var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
      //Select Box
      var e = document.getElementById("package");
      // Selected Item
      var packages = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      var arrival = document.getElementById("arrival").value;
      //var interest = document.getElementById("").value;
      var tos = document.querySelector('input[name="tos"]:checked').value;
      //var checkbox = document.getElementById("").value;;
      var matches = name.match(/\d+/g);
      var re = /^\d{4}([.\/-])\d{2}\1\d{2}$/;

      if (!name) {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
      } else {
        if (matches != null) {
          alert("Name has a number in it!: " + name);
        }
      }
      if (!email) {
        alert("Email must be filled out");
      } else {
        if (validateEmail(email) == false) {
          alert("Must enter a valid email: " + email);
        }
      }
      if (!dob) {
        alert("Date of Birth must not be empty");
      } else {
        if (!dob.match(re)) {
          alert(" Dob has Invalid date format: " + dob);

        }
      }
      if (!arrival) {
        alert("Arrival Date must not be empty");
      } else {
        if (!arrival.match(re)) {
          alert(" Dob has Invalid date format: " + arrival);

        }
      }
      if (tos != "agree") {
        alert("You must agree to the Terms of Service");
      }
    }

    function validateEmail(email) {
      return /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```